# Image processing code run time error

Tags: java, image-processing, runtime-error

I'm working on a project for my comp sci class which deals with image processing. My group and I are going to vertically flip and rotate a picture 90 degrees. The first part of my code is the sample from my teacher that turns the photo gray. I'm able to compile my code, but I get the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at Project6b.main(Project6b.java:10)`

`Press any key to continue...`

I'm not even sure if what I've coded so far works, and I can't get this to run. Can anyone help me solve my runtime error?

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Project6b
{
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
{

// I would use these, if the program is finished.
//grayscale(args[0], args[1]);
//verticalFlip(args[0], args[1]);

// I would comment the first two lines and 
//uncomment these for testing purposes.

//grayscale("Vicc.jpg", "Vicc2.jpg");
verticalFlip("Vic.png", "Vic2.png");
}
/*public static void grayscale(String originalImage, String convertedImage) throws    Exception
{
    BufferedImage bufferImg = ImageIO.read(new File(originalImage));

    int r,g,b;
    Color color = null;

    for( int x = 0; x <bufferImg.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y<bufferImg.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            int rgb = bufferImg.getRGB(x,y);
            color = new Color(rgb,true);
            r = color.getRed();
            g = color.getGreen();
            b = color.getBlue();

            color = new Color((r+g+b)/3, (r+g+b)/3, (r+g+b)/3);
            bufferImg.setRGB(x,y, color.getRGB());
        }
    }
    File outputfile = new File(convertedImage);
    ImageIO.write(bufferImg, "png", outputfile);
} */
public static void verticalFlip(String originalImage, String convertedImage) throws Exception
{
  BufferedImage bufferImg = ImageIO.read(new File(originalImage));
  BufferedImage bufferImgOut = new BufferedImage(bufferImg.getWidth(),bufferImg.getHeight(), bufferImg.getType());


    for (int x = 0; x < bufferImg.getWidth(); x++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < bufferImg.getHeight(); y++) 
      {
        int px = bufferImg.getRGB(x, y);
        int destY = bufferImg.getHeight() - y - 1;

        bufferImg.setRGB(x, destY, px);

      }
    }
    File outputfile = new File(convertedImage);
    ImageIO.write(bufferImgOut, "png", outputfile);
} 
//public static void Rotate(String originalImage, String convertedImage) throws       Exception
//{

//}
}
```

Comment: Did you pass in any arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when you don't pass any arguments at start up, like [reimeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871026/reimeus) already mentioned.

If you are using an **IDE** like **Eclipse** or **Netbeans**, there should be some kind of start cfg where you can enter the arguments, which should be passed to the app. In case you are launching your app from the command line, use:

`java Project6b Jack.jpg Jack2.jpg`

`java PROGRAM INPUT-IMAGE OUTPUT-IMAGE`

Then you can change your `main` respectively:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
{
    // I would use these, if the program is finished.
    grayscale(args[0], args[1]);
    verticalFlip(args[0], args[1]);

    // I would comment the first two lines and 
    //uncomment these for testing purposes.

    //grayscale("Jack.jpg", "Jack.jpg");
    //verticalFlip("Jack.jpg", "Jack.jpg");
}
```

(If you use the function calls at the bottom, you don't need to pass any arguments. This is good for quick debugging.)
Hope it helps!

Regarding `verticalFlip`:

```
public static void verticalFlip(String originalImage, String convertedImage)
            throws Exception {
    BufferedImage bufferImg = ImageIO.read(new File(originalImage));
    // create a new Image, which will be your output img, so that 
    // you do NOT override some pixels in your source img - you'll need them.
    BufferedImage bufferImgOut = new BufferedImage(bufferImg.getWidth(), bufferImg.getHeight(), bufferImg.getType());

    for (int x = 0; x < bufferImg.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bufferImg.getHeight(); y++) {
            int px = bufferImg.getRGB(x, y);
            int destY = bufferImg.getHeight() - y - 1;
            // your x-coordinate should stay the same, since you only flip vertically.
            bufferImgOut.setRGB(x, destY, px);

        }
    }
    File outputfile = new File(convertedImage);
    ImageIO.write(bufferImgOut, "png", outputfile);
}
```

Comment: Okay, um I think I get what you're saying. I just started this comp sci class so I'm not the best... but am I supposed to take the `java Project6b Jack.jpg Jack2.jpg`

Comment: sorry, am I supposed to that that line I just highlighted and put that on my `public class Project6b` line? and where do I put the `java PROGRAM INPUT-IMAGE OUTPUT-IMAGE` line in my code? and for the flipping method... I'm really not sure what I'm doing... kind of just figuring it out as I go. How should I fix the code so the whole thing flips?

Comment: Okay, I used the main method you had, but now I get this error,

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`
        `at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)`
        `at Project6b.grayscale(Project6b.java:23)`
        `at Project6b.main(Project6b.java:18)`
`Press any key to continue...`

Comment: Ok I corrected your flip method. How exactly do you launch your main method or program respectively? In this case, when your image is not in the same folder as your .class file, you have to adjust the path - e.g. `java Project6b ../images/Jack.jpg ../images/Jack2.jpg`. You know what I mean?

Comment: I was using JCreator... do I have to use Command Prompt directly?

Comment: oh! Yeah! I moved the file into the folder where my program is. But, I ran it this time, nothing happened... It just said press any key to continue...

Comment: Ok yeah check your folder for a new image.

Comment: Okay, I checked the folder, and now the whole image is black... am I not doing something right?

Comment: I see what happens here. Your image is a **jpg** and you try to save it as **png**: see `ImageIO.write(bufferImg, "png", outputfile);`. Just use a png image and it should be fine.

Comment: Maybe this wasn't a problem, works for me either way.

Comment: Okay I changed the input file to a png, but it does the same thing... it's still all black

Comment: Did you try to only use the `grayscale` function, to see if the black image already occurs there?

Comment: Okay the grayscale works by itself but when i put the flip method by its self, it turns it black.

Comment: Could you change your post, so that I can check your actual code?

Comment: Found It! :D `bufferImg.setRGB(x, destY, px);` should be `bufferImgOut.setRGB(x, destY, px);`

Comment: As in the code I already posted ;) Otherwise you would only save `bufferImgOut`, which is a newly created image and therefore black. So you have to fill it with data like .setRGB....